# Typescript coding conventions to avoid import declaration conflicts

Tags: typescript

TypeScript properly errors when trying to do something like

```js
import * as path from "path"

let path = path.join("a", "b", "c")
```

because the `Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'path'`.

There are basically two options:

1. Importing the `path` module under a different name.
2. Avoiding `path` as a variable name.

This seems to be a common conflict. I'm not familiar with common coding conventions in TypeScript. I'm wondering there are recommendations how to handle such conflicts in standard coding conventions?

In particular, if going for option 1, is there a common module renaming scheme like `pathMod`, `mPath`, `m_path`, `path_module` or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** I don't think there's any more specific convention that just picking your names to avoid conflicts.

> In particular, if going for option 1, is there a common module renaming scheme like pathMod, mPath, m_path, path_module or so?

Not that I'm aware of.

Re avoiding conflicts: Using more specific variable names often helps. If the path is for a CSV file (for instance), perhaps `csvPath` instead of `path`:

```
let csvPath = path.join("a", "b", "c");
```

You might also just import `join`:

```
import { join } from "path"

let path = join("a", "b", "c");
```

...but of course, that just moves the goalposts — what if you want to have a variable called `join`? :-)